# Google Sign In iOS SDK - Carthage support

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, carthage

Do you guys know if there is a way to install Google Sign In iOS SDK using Carthage ?
So far, I think that they are just using cocoapods, I couldn't install the SDK using Carthage.

Is there a URL for google bug reports related to iOS SDK ?
For checking if it's already planned to support Carthage, and otherwise, for creating a ticket, for requesting its support.

Answer (score 3):

There are also instructions provided for integration without using Cocoapods at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/

This provides a framework and a bundle which you can just drag into your project. There isn't a need to use Carthage in this case. And if you are using Carthage already for other dependencies, this method of integration will not interfere with it.

Comment: Thanks @Abizern ! Yeah, I'm integrating the SDK without Cocoapods currently. I was just wondering if Google planned to allow integration with Carthage as well. Now that Carthage is used a lot today, I see the benefit of adding that support. It's easier to download/install all frameworks using Carthage/cocoapods Vs integrating them manually.
I just hope that they plan to add Carthage support soon.

Comment: It's a bit less work to keep up to date using Carthage. Copying in a new framework bundle isn't that bad but it requires more steps than `carthage update google-sdk`. And you can update multiple dependencies with one command if everything is managed by Carthage. There are still reasons and advantages here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem while working on a project that used Carthage to manage multiple dependencies, so I created a dynamic version of the Google Sign-In framework that is compatible with Carthage:

https://github.com/fabio914/GoogleSignIn-iOS/

You just need to add this to your Cartfile:

```
github "https://github.com/fabio914/GoogleSignIn-iOS" ~> 4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks Firebase have published a Google Sign In binary dependency for Carthage - it's especially handy if you use it in conjunction with Firebase Auth.

To use it, add this entry to your Cartfile:

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseGoogleSignInBinary.json"
```

At the time of writing, as with everything else Firebase related, Carthage support for this is experimental - make sure also you don't include any Firebase related frameworks in the input/output file lists for the `copy-frameworks` build phase.  [You can find all further Firebase specific instructions for Carthage here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md).